# Unicorn cannot find gem on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

I just installed a new gem on my rails application. Everything works fine on the dev machine.

Once I deploy the application to my production server, I get an `Uninitialized constant` in my `unicorn.log` and the application won't run.

**I can run the application with the `rails s` server, so the files are 100% there.** I'm assuming that it is a unicorn problem.

Any ideas on how to debug this?

EDIT: Added stacktrace

```
E, [2013-05-19T09:11:56.596020 #14042] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Rabl (NameError)
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/releases/20130519131101/config/initializers/rabl_init.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/releases/20130519131101/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
config.ru:4:in `require'
config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
config.ru:1:in `new'
config.ru:1:in `<main>'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.5.0/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `eval'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.5.0/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `block in builder'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.5.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:718:in `call'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.5.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:718:in `build_app!'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.5.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:591:in `init_worker_process'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.5.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:611:in `worker_loop'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.5.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500:in `spawn_missing_workers'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.5.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:511:in `maintain_worker_count'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.5.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:277:in `join'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.5.0/bin/unicorn:121:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: is your 'rails s' starting in production mode?

Comment: Yes. I do `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails s`

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the gem in the `Gemfile`. Also, you need to do a `bundle install` after making changes to the `Gemfile`

Comment: Yeap. I'm deploying the application using capistrano, so everything gets updated once I deploy. That wouldn't explain why I can use the `rails s` server, and not unicorn

Comment: I am not sure if `capistrano` does a `bundle install` after deploying. You might want to confirm that if you aren't sure either.

Comment: It does. The gem is available in the rails server and console.

Comment: Can you share the exact error you get in `unicorn.log`? or is `Uninitialized constant` the only thing you get?

Comment: Can you also share the `.bundle/config` file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30211/discussion-between-alexbrand-and-draxxxeus)

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to your deploy.rb file

```
before 'deploy', 'bundleinstall'  # update RVM

task :bundleinstall do
  run "cd /home/#{user}/#{application}/#{fetch :app_env}/current && bundle install", :shell => fetch(:rvm_shell)
end
```